# How to validate AES decryption was successful?

Tags: cryptography, aes, md5

I'm developing a local file encryption/decryption software (AES-256 CBC),
which I want to validate decryption was successful or not.

so I decided to add an additional MD5 hash of plain data to end of plain data and encrypt it together,
and when decryption, calculate the MD5 hash of decryption data(except last additional MD5 hash) and
compare it with last additional MD5 hash.

I want to know if this idea is safe to use.

Is it a bad idea?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not about software development, but rather about the security of a specific encryption construction for authenticated encryption. [crypto.se] is much better suited for this type of question, but it is probably answered there already

Comment: @ArtjomB. Oh, I didn't know that site exists. thx

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Cryptography Stack Exchange](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/) or [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: *"I want to know if this idea is safe to use...."* - No. *"... add an additional MD5 hash of plain data to end of plain data and encrypt it together..."* - That's the scheme suggested in the [Handbook of Applied Cryptography, Section 9.6](http://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/hac/). It is provably insecure. Also see [Authenticated Encryption](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Authenticated_Encryption) on the Crypto++ wiki. Its written in the context of a C++ security library, but it applies to data security in general.

Comment: I think the aswers and comments surely are very valid but are missing the question. He is asking if adding a hash to the plain text message to recognize that the decription was succesful can be done with an MD5 hash or if that poses some risk. My answer was downvoted. But perhaps someone can provide a better answer in the scope of the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also use MAC to verify your decryption.
The main difference between MAC and Hash code is conceptual. hashes are used to guarantee the integrity of data, a MAC guarantees integrity AND authentication.

This means that a hashcode is blindly generated from the message without any kind of external input: what you obtain is something that can be used to check if the message got any alteration during its travel.

A MAC instead uses a private key as the seed to the hash function it uses when generating the code: this should assure the receiver that, not only the message hasn't been modified, but also who sent it is what we were expecting: otherwise an attacker couldn't know the private key used to generate the code.

```
Cryptographic primitive | Hash |    MAC    | Digital
Security Goal           |      |           | signature
------------------------+------+-----------+-------------
Integrity               |  Yes |    Yes    |   Yes
Authentication          |  No  |    Yes    |   Yes
Non-repudiation         |  No  |    No     |   Yes
------------------------+------+-----------+-------------
Kind of keys            | none | symmetric | asymmetric
                        |      |    keys   |    keys
```

Comment: MAC is not always the same. It is recommended to use [encrypt-then-MAC](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/202/13022).

Comment: *"A MAC instead uses a private key..."* - I believe MACs traditionally use a shared key, not a private key. *"a MAC guarantees integrity AND authentication..."* - this isn't exactly correct. Since both parties share the MAC key, you can't authenticate the origin of a message because either party could have produced it.

Comment: @jww I prefer the term "secret key" or indeed "shared secret key" for that, but sometimes the term "private key" is used as well. I think that is dumb because it is hard for a key to be shared *and* private. You've got a point, but in a sense the message itself is authenticated to be at least from one of the parties holding the key.

Comment: A few comments: only HMAC uses a key that is used as input of the hash, rather than to "seed it"; other algorithms such as AES-CMAC use a cipher, for instance. Furthermore, the integrity provided by a hash is only against random change, not against adversaries who can simply recalculate the hash. It is recommended to use a separate key although with HMAC the security penalty of using the same key is mostly theoretical in nature.

Answer (score -1):

I've read in many posts that MD5 is not safe anymore but, you are using it as a checksum not as a session id or a password hash. If an attack on the MD5 is not a concern because it is inside encrypted code and it is not being used as a password hash, nor a session id, or similar, I think you can use it, but if you want to be on the safe side change MD5 for an SHA-2 digest.